# Как работать со встраиваемой БД?

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, развертывание

Я использую Intellij IDEA для сборки проекта(javafx + hibernate), но после создания jar файла база не может быть найдена (чисто теоретически я могу создать базу при первой попытке подключения, но мне нужно подключение к существующей).
Собственно вопрос в том, как сконнектиться с базой после сборки проекта. В конфигурационном файле (hibernate.cfg.xml) я перепробовал все возможные написание относительных путей к базе и всё работает только если я укажу абсолютный путь. Но мне же надо распространять приложение. Как сделать так, чтобы после установки приложения база помещалась в папку относительно запускаемого файла? И как указать путь к ней?
Или, если сам алгоритм не верен, как сделать правильно?

Comment: Насчёт относительного пути в Hibernate: это возможно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207826/hibernate-h2-database-relative-path

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Складываете свою БД в ресурс, который пакуете внутри jar

2) При первом запуске читаете свою БД из ресурса, например так:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mybd.db");
```

3) Записываете БД в локальный каталог, относительно себя, например так:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("./mydb.db"));
```

4) Напускаете Hibernate на чтение БД из этого файла

**Update** (по следам дискуссии в комментариях)

Для того, чтобы каталог создавался в том же каталоге, где лежит архив JAR, нужно сделать что-то типа:

```
String currentPath=MyMainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

Грубо говоря, определяем где находится ваш `main()` (а он лежит там же где находится сам JAR) и по этому пути создаем каталог куда кидаем свою БД.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за Ваш ответ, не найдя другого варианта попробовал предложенный Вами, но указав путь "./mydb.db" файл создаётся в корневой директории, а не в папке с джарником как такое возможно?

Comment: А вы откуда запускаете сам jar? Каталог создается видимо там где вы запускаете jar.

Comment: Из папки проекта. Intellij IDEA создаю артифакт... по умолчанию он создаётся в /out/artifacts/TestFX

Comment: Запустите сами вручную jar - и посмотрите где создается каталог. Текущий каталог это не всегда каталог где лежит jar, а каталог откуда запускается jar

Comment: Кажется получилось, но как сделать чтобы jar запускался из того же каталога? То есть, сейчас я через консольку запустил. Может глупый вопрос...

Comment: см. апдейт ответа